# HTML5 reset slider to min position

Tags: jquery, html, slider

What I am trying to do is get the slider to reset it's value and animation position to zero but I can't find how.

> http://jsfiddle.net/v4gNL/1359/

**HTML5:**

```
<body>

  <span>  
            <select id="selectSymptom">
                <option value="option" >Select Option</option>
                <option value="option1" >Option 1</option>
                <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
                <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
                <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
                <option value="option6">Option 6</option>

            </select>
        </span>
  <span style='display:none;' id="slider"> <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" step="0.1" id="rangeValue"><label id="text">0</label></span>

</body>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#selectSymptom').on('change', function() {
  $("#text").text(0);

  var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
  $("#slider").show();
});
$("#rangeValue").mousemove(function() {
  $("#text").text($("#rangeValue").val());
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set it's value to 0 in the change event of the dropdown

```
  $('#rangeValue').val(0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v4gNL/1361/

Comment: Oh god, i tried it, must have done some syntax error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `$("#slider input").val(0);` in your jquery code.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4gNL/1365/)

```
$('#selectSymptom').on('change', function() {
  $("#text").text(0);
  $("#slider input").val(0);
  var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
  $("#slider").show();
});
$("#rangeValue").mousemove(function() {
  $("#text").text($("#rangeValue").val());
});
```